# Calculate different between two dates result I need months and days only (without Year)

Tags: java

> I got this class in java to calculate efferent between two dates but
>   the result coming with year I need this only month and days. Example 1
>   year 2 months 5 days is result. I need Result 14 month 5 days

Java code for date different calculation

```
public String getPeriod(Date a, Date b)     {

        Calendar startDay = Calendar.getInstance();
        startDay.setTimeInMillis(a.getTime());

        //create calendar object for current day
        Calendar endDay = Calendar.getInstance();
        endDay.setTimeInMillis(b.getTime());

        //Get difference between years
        years = endDay.get(Calendar.YEAR) - startDay.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int deathMonth = endDay.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        int openMonth = startDay.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;

        months = deathMonth - openMonth;
        //if month difference is in negative then reduce years by one 
        //and calculate the number of months.
        if (months < 0)
        {
            years--;
            months = 12 - openMonth + deathMonth;

            if (endDay.get(Calendar.DATE) < startDay.get(Calendar.DATE))
                months--;
        } 
        else if (months == 0 && endDay.get(Calendar.DATE) < startDay.get(Calendar.DATE))
        {
                years--;
                months = 11;
        }

            //Calculate the days
        if (endDay.get(Calendar.DATE) > startDay.get(Calendar.DATE))
            days = endDay.get(Calendar.DATE) - startDay.get(Calendar.DATE);

        else if (endDay.get(Calendar.DATE) < startDay.get(Calendar.DATE))
        {
            int today = endDay.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            endDay.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
            days = endDay.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - startDay.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + today;
        } 
        else
        {
            days = 0;
            if (months == 12)
            {
                years++;
                months = 0;
            }
        }

        return (months+","+days+","+years);
    }
```

Comment: Well of course the result comes with years when you include years in the returned value! What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: If you are using at least Java 8, consider using [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider implementing your `getPeriod()` method using java's [date-time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/datetime/index.html) that was introduced in Java 8. Below is such an implementation:

```java
/* Required imports.
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
 */
private static String getPeriod(LocalDate start, LocalDate end) {
    long months = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(start, end);
    long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start.plusMonths(months), end);
    return String.format("%d months %d days", months, days);
}
```

If you call the method like so:

```java
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(2020, Month.JANUARY, 1);
LocalDate end = LocalDate.of(2020, Month.APRIL, 29);
getPeriod(start, end);
```

The method will return the following string:

```
3 months 28 days
```

Refer to the [Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) trail in Oracle's java tutorials.

Comment: No I send date to start date and end date is String period = calc.getPeriod(dtOpenDate.getDate(), dtDeathDate.getDate());

Comment: and I need to get date from JDayChooser

Comment: @derickbarthelot To convert an old-fashioned `Date` to `LocalDate` use `yourDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate()`. After that you can enjoy the simplicity of this answer and the good design of java.time, the modern Java date and time API.